# ElastAlert flatline not finding results

Tags: lucene, kibana, elastalert

Creating a `flatline` alert type using the ElastAlert framework.

When I use the query in the Kibana UI with the exact same syntax it returns results, but ElastAlert isn't returning any results.

Here's my elastalert-rule-file.xml

```
name: Test Flatline
type: flatline
run_every:
    seconds: 15
relalert: 
    minutes: 0
es_host: localhost
es_port: 9200
threshold: 1
timeframe: 
    minutes: 5
index: my-index-*
filter: 
- query:
    query_string:
        query: "_type:metric"  # this returns results in both kibana and elastalert
        #query: "_type:metric AND _exists_:My\ Field\ With\ Spaces.value" # this returns results in kibana but not in elastalert

timestamp_type: unix_ms
alert:
  - command
command: ["my-bash-script.sh"]
```

So I tried play around with the query and if I just specify `_type:metric` then the search results in Kibana seem to match those in ElastAlert.

However when I attempt to use the query with the `_exists_` lucene syntax in the second query ElastAlert doesn't return anything while Kibana seems to be fine with the syntax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...just forgot to post an answer.

Apparently for the field with spaces you need to escape the backslashes so the line in question would look like this:

```
query: "_type:metric AND _exists_:My\\ Field\\ With\\ Spaces.value"
```

Furthermore, in the special case where you are using Ansible (YAML) configuration you need to add a backslash to escape each backslash.

So the entry in a YAML file would look something like this:

```
query: "My\\\\ field\\\\ With\\\\ Spaces.value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid escaping by using double quotes for the field data:

```
query: '_type:metric AND _exists_:"My Field With Spaces.value"'
```